# Has anyone connected Tridion with Digital River for payment processing?

Tags: content-manager, ecl, external-integrations

We are using Digital River to host an online store front (as well as process the transactions) and now we would like to take control of that store front in Tridion while still passing to Digital River for transaction processing.

Has anyone connected Tridion with Digital River in this capacity?

Comment: what sort of connection are you thinking about, can you supply some details about what is required?

Comment: @BartKoopman We'd want a way to surface some of the product information that is stored in Digital River in Tridion so that it can be exposed on the Content Delivery side. Probably expose Digital River as an ECL for this. On the Content Delivery side we'd submit a request using Digital River's direct-to-cart functionality. I'm really interested in learning if anyone has done an integration with Digital River and what the experience was like.

Answer (score 4):

I would imagine any integration between Tridion and Digital River would (or at least should) be quite loose.

The most I would expect to need to do is publish a configuration file (gateway url, gateway keys etc..) or output specific markup in a Page or Component Template like JavaScript or Form Fields.

Payment processing takes place on the Content Delivery side of the house, and besides content aspects (which Tridion should be used for) there is no real need for Tridion to be involved in payment processing.